# Junit - Mockito - how to setUp mocked objects properly

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I'm creating tests for different methods, but all these methods are pretty similar - adding something to Day.

I have created Day object for test, and I have mocked some things such as Database. But I have problems with setting up this properly.

For example: one method which returns Day to use this Day in my `addSomething()` method is like this:

```
Item item = dbService.get(tableName, Collections.singletonList(primaryKey));
String measurementsJSON = item.getJSON("measurements");
```

I've mocked DB and Item and I wanted to setup 'before' things so I did this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activitiesService = new ActivitiesService(databaseControllerMock);
    when(eq(item).getJSON(anyString())).thenReturn(anyString());
}
```

But in this case I'm getting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at service.activity.service.ActivitiesServiceTest.setUp(ActivitiesServiceTest.java:45) //this line with "when..."
```

And other errors:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>       Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>       -> at service.activity.service.ActivitiesServiceTest.setUp(ActivitiesServiceTest.java:45)
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>   Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>   when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null); doThrow(new
>   RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>   verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
>   Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

As the message says

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
```

Change

```
when(eq(item).getJSON(anyString())).thenReturn(anyString());
```

to some string return, something like

```
when(eq(item).getJSON(anyString())).thenReturn("{somekey:somevalue}");
```

I am assuming you want to return a json representation as string

Comment: Exactly. the `anyString()` is an argument matcher and you can't use it as a return value for a mocked method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use when clause inside setUp method.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
     activitiesService = new ActivitiesService(databaseControllerMock);
}

@Test
public void testSomething() {
      when(eq(item).getJSON(anyString())).thenReturn(anyString());
}
```

Besides, if you can add your class to want to test, we can help more easily.